# Can not send Drupal notification mail from localhost with mercury XAMPP

Tags: drupal-7, xampp, sendmail

I'm building a Drupal website, and I can not send notification from my localhost. I built my site on an XAMPP server, and run mercury, here my php.ini configuration:

SMTP = localhost

smtp_port = 25

sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost

I've tested my mercury email by sending mail to external mail account with from mail named 'tenxanh@tenxanh.vn' and successed. In Drupal site information I type tenxanh@tenxanh.vn(my domain is tenxanh.vn). But it didn't send.

So anyone have config drupal notification mail? Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to mess with the server configuration, one alternative is to use the [SMTP Authentication Support](http://drupal.org/project/smtp) module.  This will allow you to use an external mail server; if you have access to such a server, this is a reliable, generally trouble-free way to get up and running.

Comment: if I use this module, and want to send notification mail via my tenxanh.vn domain, so must I config my mercury? I'm use SMTP end to end server version . And how can I set user name and password for 'SMTP authen module'?? I don't know any things about mail server. Can you help me?

Comment: Your mail server configuration would be provided by your web/e-mail host.  You don't need to configure your Mercury server at all as long as you have an external mail host.  This has nothing to do with Drupal; you just need a username and password for the SMTP host for your domain.  If you don't have one, it used to be you could use Google Apps for free, but that is no longer open (as of a couple weeks ago).  Instead, you can find some third-party mail host.

Comment: Yes I also tried Google Apps last week. I tested sending mail from mercury with email address 'tenxanh@tenxanh.vn' or any things include '@tenxanh.vn' and it's good, so all things left to do is making a right config for drupal, can you help me sendding notification mail via mercury?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Mercury so I can't help you with that.  The advantage of using the SMTP module is that if for some reason your local configuration changes/you move the site to a different server/you go live, etc. you can still use the same mail settings.